# UIGestureRecognizer doesnt work and makes app slow

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, location, uigesturerecognizer

In map view, I want to make that if user touches anywhere in the map, app stops updating location..but seems like nothing happens and it takes around 10-15 seconds for actions to work in the app ( makes app really slow and laggy ) I have been using this code:

```
 @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        StopUpdate.hidden = true
        Longi.hidden = true
        Lati.hidden = true
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapClose"))
}

func tapClose(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    StopUpdate.hidden = true
    UpdateLocation.hidden = false
}
```

Because of the GestureRecognizer my app is slow and laggy.Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way to add UITapGesture

```
class DashVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
}
```

define tapgesture in viewdidload like this

```
let tapDashBoard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DashVC.DashBoardTapped(_:)))
    tapDashBoard.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapDashBoard)
```

and action

```
    func DashBoardTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
}
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'DashVC' ? How to fix that?

Comment: it is name of your ViewController.replace with your ViewController Name

Comment: fixed that but im geting new Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?' at line tapDashBoard.delegate = self

Comment: It work! Does it suppose to work wih only Right mouse button? Clicking left mouse button does nothing..

Comment: if my answer works than please accept an answer and UpVote.

Comment: Do you know why only with click it stops, but can I make if I zooom out or hold somewhere?

Comment: there are so many gestures,depends upon our requirement.
you can also handle two taps 
like         tapDashBoard.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

Comment: what you want to do exactly.tell me

Comment: Can I make that if I drag/zoom in-out/ or I do anything in my app, button stops doing its action?

Comment: Because right now it stops ONLY IF I press somewhere

Comment: no no no, I want to do this locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

Comment: Because right now, while program is traching location, I cant zoom in/out or do anything else because "Current location" dot is always at the center

Comment: Go through this link to refer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044148/making-the-map-zoom-to-user-location-and-annotation-swift-2

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html found everything here :)

Comment: Good.the link which i gave you is related to currentlocation and zoom location.refer

Comment: I want to do same function with UIPitchGestureRecognizer but it seems it doesnt work...im using same code just I have replaced to UIPitchGestureRecognizer everywhere..